# Self intersection number for special fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi\colon X\to Y$ be a proper morphism of smooth complex algebraic varieties with $\dim X = 2n$ and general fibers of dimension $<n$. Assume that $F := \pi^{-1}(p)$ is a an irreducible and reduced $n$-dimensional fiber, is it true that $F^2<0$?

Comment: How do you interpret $F^2$ as a number?

Comment: For simplicity asume $X$ to be complete. Then $F$ defines a class in $H^{2n}(X,\mathbb Z)$ and $F^2$ corresponds to a number via $H^{2n}(X,\mathbb Z)\times H^{2n}(X,\mathbb Z)\to H^{4n}(X,\mathbb Z)\cong\mathbb Z$.

Comment: thanks. I had read that $\pi$ was of relative dimension $n$ which is why I got confused